# Create a dataframe with a variable number of copies of each row in a source dataframe

Tags: r, apply

Say I have a dataframe

```
source <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2), COUNT=c(3,4))
```

that looks like this:

```
  ID COUNT
1  1     3
2  2     4
```

I'd like to transform this into a dataframe that has COUNT records for each ID, with a new unique ITEMID, like this

```
  ITEMID SOURCEID
1      1        1
2      2        1
3      3        1
4      4        2
5      5        2
6      6        2
7      7        2
```

I can do it with a for loop, but am looking to learn how to do this with apply type functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `apply` functions:

```
orig <- data.frame(ID=1:2,COUNT=3:4)
new <- data.frame(ITEMID=seq(sum(orig$COUNT)), SOURCEID=rep(orig$ID,times=orig$COUNT))
new
  ITEMID SOURCEID
1      1        1
2      2        1
3      3        1
4      4        2
5      5        2
6      6        2
7      7        2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(source, source$ID), with, df, {
    itemid <- seq(count)
    sourceid <- id
    data.frame(itemid, sourceid)
})
```